# debian 5.19.11 Linux: NFSv3 Input/output error while cat , 5.14 or below ok

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, mount, nfs

#### What led up to the situation?

Upgrading to kernel 5.19 and trying to read a small file from directory on the NFS server.

#### What exactly did you do (or not do) that was effective (or ineffective)?

server:

```
WinNFSd.exe -log on "F/Kernel5.19/NFS"
```

client:

```
mount -t nfs 192.168.0.21:/F/Kernel5.19/NFS /mnt/img -o noatime,nfsvers=3
cd /mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0
cat parts
```

#### What was the outcome of this action?

```
Input/output error.
```

terminal interface stuck

#### What outcome did you expect instead?

Files can be read normal ( This good outome happens with kernel 5.14 and older )

***Issue Details*** 
I have encountered a problem while using the `WinNFSd.exe` tool as a server, sharing directory on Windows 10, and with Debian 11 ( kernel version 5.19 ) as client utilizing the NFSv3 protocol for mounting. The mounting process completes without any errors, and can successfully access the directory info using the `ls` or `ls -l`. However, when I attempt to access the directory contents using the `cat` command, I receive an error message stating `Input/output error`.

I can also read the content of newly created files using cat when they are created on the client side using touch. However, if a file is created on the server side, the client can see the newly created file and get the file information with ls, but encounters an "Input/output error" when trying to read its contents with cat. That's the strange part confused me, seems like problems with access control?

Additionally, after a certain period of time, the terminal interface becomes unresponsive stuck when attempting to access the mounted directory. I'm uncertain about the exact cause triggering this issue, as the timing appears to be random. Sometimes, it takes several minutes for the unresponsiveness to occur, while in other instances, I can work for up to half an hour without any issues.

Interestingly, downgrading the kernel version to 5.14 or BELOW resolves this problem. In fact, using the same network environment, mounted directory, and mounting parameters, I tested kernel versions 6.1, 5.18, 5.15, 5.14, 5.10, and 4.19. Out of these versions, only the first three presented this issue, while the latter three low versions were able to read the contents of files within the NFS shared directory without any problems.

**NEW TEST INFO UPDATE**
**Wireshark Output**

I’m trying to read the contents of a file with an actual length of 15 and capture packets using Wireshark. I discovered that in a lower version of Linux kernel (version 4.19), the length of the NFS client request is 15 (actual length),

```
No.  Source        Destination    Protocol  Length  Info

212  192.168.0.100  192.168.0.21   NFS       206     V3 READ Call(Reply In 213), FH:0x6ee4af5f Offset: 0 Len:15
213  192.168.0.21   192.168.0.100  NFS       202     V3 READ Reply(Call In 212) Len:15
```

but in a higher version of Linux kernel (version 5.19), the request length is 4096.

```
No.  Source        Destination    Protocol  Length  Info

443  192.168.0.100  192.168.0.21  NFS       206     V3 READ Call(Reply In 446), FH:0x6ee4af5f Offset: 0 Len:4096
444  192.168.0.21   192.168.0.100 TCP       1514    2049->714 [ACK] Seq=44717 Ack=4613 Win=8210 Len=1460 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
445  192.168.0.21   192.168.0.100 TCP       1514    2049->714 [ACK] Seq=46177 Ack=4613 Win=8210 Len=1460 [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]
446  192.168.0.21   192.168.0.100 NFS       1362    V3 READ Reply(Call In 443) Len:15
```

I’m not sure if this phenomenon is related to the “Input/output error.”

Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

#### Here are the specific details of the problematic test environment:

***Server:***

- Operating System: Windows 10
- NFS Server Tool: WinNFSd.exe 2.4.0

***Client:***

- Operating System: 
  Debian 11.0
- Kernel Version: 
  `Linux gpc 5.19.0-0.deb11.2-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 5.19.11-1~bpo11+1 (2022-10-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

***Protocol:***

- NFS Version: NFSv3
- nfs-common/oldstable,now 1:1.3.4-6 amd64 [installed]
- rpcbind/oldstable,now 1.2.5-9 amd64 [installed,automatic]

***Mount CMD***

```
root@gpc:mount -t nfs 192.168.0.21:/F/Kernel5.19/NFS /mnt/img -o noatime,nfsvers=3
```

***Observations:***

```
root@gpc:/mnt/img# ls -l 
total 4 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul 28 2023 GPCImageV4.0

root@gpc:/mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0# ls -l 
total 2400393 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1529 Jul 26 18:54 blkdev.list 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1424 Jul 26 18:54 blkid.list 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13562 Jul 26 18:54 clonezilla-img 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 300 Jul 26 18:54 dev-fs.list 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 26 18:54 disk 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1207 Jul 26 18:54 efi-nvram.dat 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 201 Nov 2 2022 GantryConfiguration.xml 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22373 Jul 26 18:54 Info-dmi.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 236 Jul 26 18:54 Info-img-id.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jul 26 18:54 Info-img-size.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27602 Jul 26 18:54 Info-lshw.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1592 Jul 26 18:54 Info-lspci.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1539 Jul 26 18:54 Info-OS-prober.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 200 Jul 26 18:54 Info-packages.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 96 Jul 26 18:54 Info-saved-by-cmd.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4724 Jul 26 18:54 Info-smart.txt 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jul 26 18:54 parts 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2158265 Jul 26 18:54 sda1.vfat-ptcl-img.gz 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2210653199 Jul 26 18:54 sda2.ext4-ptcl-img.gz 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 225310835 Jul 26 18:53 sda3.ext4-ptcl-img.gz 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4227536 Jul 26 18:52 sda4.ext4-ptcl-img.gz 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7246389 Jul 26 18:52 sda5.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2314988 Jul 26 18:52 sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.gz 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5948542 Jul 26 18:52 sda7.ext4-ptcl-img.gz 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jul 26 18:54 sda-chs.sf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17408 Jul 26 18:54 sda-gpt-1st 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Jul 26 18:54 sda-gpt-2nd 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17920 Jul 26 18:54 sda-gpt.gdisk 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 967 Jul 26 18:54 sda-gpt.sgdisk 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Jul 26 18:54 sda-mbr 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 644 Jul 26 18:54 sda-pt.parted 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 540 Jul 26 18:54 sda-pt.parted.compact 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1229 Jul 26 18:54 sda-pt.sf 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Jul 26 18:52 swappt-sda8.info

root@gpc:/mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0# cat parts 
cat: parts: Input/output error 

root@gpc:/mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0# cat disk 
cat: disk: Input/output error
```

#### Here are the specific details of the normal test environment:

***Server:***

- Operating System: Windows 10
- NFS Server Tool: WinNFSd.exe 2.4.0

***Client:***

- Operating System: 
  Debian 9.1
- Kernel Version: 
  `Linux gpc 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.88-1+deb9u1 (2018-05-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

***Protocol:***

- NFS Version: NFSv3
- nfs-common/now 1:1.3.4-2.1ubuntu5.5 amd64 [installed,local]
- rpcbind/now 0.2.3-0.6ubuntu0.18.04.4 amd64 [installed,local]

***Mount CMD***

```
root@gpc:mount -t nfs 192.168.0.21:/F/Kernel5.19/NFS /mnt/img -o noatime,nfsvers=3
```

***Observations:***

```
root@gpc:/mnt/img# ls -l 
total 4 
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 Jul 28  2023 GPCImageV4.0

root@gpc:/mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0# ls -l 
total 2400393
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1529 Jul 26  2023 blkdev.list
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1424 Jul 26  2023 blkid.list
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13562 Jul 26  2023 clonezilla-img
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 300 Jul 26  2023 dev-fs.list
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Jul 26  2023 disk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1207 Jul 26  2023 efi-nvram.dat
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 201 Nov  2  2022 GantryConfiguration.xml
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22373 Jul 26  2023 Info-dmi.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 236 Jul 26  2023 Info-img-id.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 61 Jul 26  2023 Info-img-size.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27602 Jul 26  2023 Info-lshw.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1592 Jul 26  2023 Info-lspci.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1539 Jul 26  2023 Info-OS-prober.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 200 Jul 26  2023 Info-packages.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 96 Jul 26  2023 Info-saved-by-cmd.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4724 Jul 26  2023 Info-smart.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jul 26  2023 parts
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2158265 Jul 26  2023 sda1.vfat-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2210653199 Jul 26  2023 sda2.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 225310835 Jul 26  2023 sda3.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4227536 Jul 26  2023 sda4.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7246389 Jul 26  2023 sda5.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2314988 Jul 26  2023 sda6.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 5948542 Jul 26  2023 sda7.ext4-ptcl-img.gz
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Jul 26  2023 sda-chs.sf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17408 Jul 26  2023 sda-gpt-1st
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16384 Jul 26  2023 sda-gpt-2nd
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17920 Jul 26  2023 sda-gpt.gdisk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 967 Jul 26  2023 sda-gpt.sgdisk
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 512 Jul 26  2023 sda-mbr
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 644 Jul 26  2023 sda-pt.parted
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 540 Jul 26  2023 sda-pt.parted.compact
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1229 Jul 26  2023 sda-pt.sf
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Jul 26  2023 swappt-sda8.info

root@gpc:/mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0# cat parts
sda1 sda2 sda3 sda4 sda5 sda6 sda7

root@gpc:/mnt/img/GPCImageV4.0# cat disk
sda
```

Comment: There is no good reason to upgrade Debian 11 to kernel 5.19 . Either stick to 5.10 or upgrade to 6.1 from debian-backports. Don't attempt to change the kernel compile options yourself before having tried the provided one. You question looks like a bug report, but there's no bug to report by mentioning you upgraded to 5.19 which has been EOL for 9 months.

Comment: @A.B FYI - I ran kernel up to 6.0 on debian 11 with no issue (kernel was from bullseye-backports)

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't read everything. Suppose still we can confirm there is a bug in the kernel. The only answer to having found such bug is to switch to a supported kernel. I'm just saying it's not even worth checking the question further before the kernel is 5.10 or 6.1 (or 6.4).

Comment: I read better and 6.1 is mentioned. But still this looks like a bug report, not a UL SE Q/A

Comment: Actually, i tried LTS like 5.15 and 6.1, they all have this wired problem.

Comment: You could try and find the commit that fails it: https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/bug-bisect.html , then your bug report would be worth reporting (not here, but on Linux)

Comment: Is it possible that the problem is caused by the winnfsd.exe tool on the Windows side?

Comment: It is certainly caused by that. But that doesn't mean something that did work before should stop working after when the change is on the other side. But again, I don't see how this question fits here.

Comment: @A.B In fact, I found that WinNFSd.exe stopped receiving updates in 2016. Do you have any recommendations for an NFS server tool like WinNFSd.exe on the Win10?

Comment: No: this is a Unix/Linux stack exchange. I don't use Windows. Your question was asked on the wrong site.

Comment: @A.B Exactly, I will give it a try from this perspective and see if this issue reproducible. thanks a lot.

Comment: @A.B hi, after my test, it seems none of winNFSd.exe business. You could my new puzzling here if you are interested (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/753511/linux-nfsv3-input-output-error-while-cat-kernel-5-14-or-below-ok)

Comment: You shoudn't ask a new question (as told in the other question). The least you can do is test with a NFS server running with Unix/Linux rather than Windows to compare.